# Route not set in AppServiceProvider in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, provider

I want to set route in AppServiceProvider to redirect. But the route not set there.

```
            public function boot(){ .....if (empty($domainItem)) {
            \Route::get('/invalid', '\App\Http\Controllers\MainController@invalid')->name('invalid');

            return \Redirect::route('/invalid');
        } .....}
```

I can see "invalid" route in route:list but i see this error when i run the code :
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [/invalid] not defined.

Comment: Providers should not redirect make it as an middleware instead, providers are also used in context where it cant redirect, jobs commands etc. and im not even certain it will work, as to how the providers get initilized and or if a redirect will hit the webpage

Comment: because the route is named `invalid` not `/invalid`    (`'/invalid` would be a path, URI, not the route name)

Comment: Try using the global `redirect` helper. Try something like `return redirect('/invalid');`

Comment: Thank you both comments help me. I set a middleware instead in provider @mrhn and it work :)

Comment: For future readers (assuming this doesn't get deleted), the issue is not with the first parameter of `get`, but with the `name` function since the route would not exist. That would be evident if OP ran the command `php route list`.